# What working directory do I have to be in to connect to a MySQL server in R

Tags: mysql, r, odbc

I am using a Windows 7 64-bit computer, trying to connect to an ODBC driver directly with R. I tried downloading the `RMySQL` package as a source, but for some reason it won't install and just leaves error messages like this:

```
* installing *source* package 'RMySQL' ...
** package 'RMySQL' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'RMySQL'
* removing 'C:/Users/jizzard/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RMySQL'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\jizzard\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" C:\Users\jizzard\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8qnScH/downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status
```

So I'm trying to use the `RODBC` package instead. I've got my database as an ODBC driver shortcut (Verizon DMP)

[image]

but when I try to type `con = odbcConnect("Verizon Fios")` in R, no connection is established. What is going wrong?

Comment: Simply googling your error message led [here](http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/) which might help with RMySQL.

Comment: Never mind, I had to add my `uid` and `pwd` to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`odbcConnect()` requires your username (`uid`) and password (`pwd`):

```
    odbcConnect(dsn, uid, pwd, ...)
```